# Validate basic types (String, Integer, ...) parameters on Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

I've found a lot of tutorials and documentation about the input validation using Spring (https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) and exploiting JSR 303. But all these documentations are about how validate a custom bean (like User, Employer, or classes like that). 
I actually need to validate a controller accepting basic types like String, Integer and Lists. My API controller looks like

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value="/v1/{var:.*}/resource", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Response> readDocuments(
        @PathVariable(value = "var") String param1,
        @RequestParam(value = "param2", required = false, defaultValue = "string1") String param2,
        @RequestParam(value = "param3") List<String> param3,
        @RequestParam(value = "param4", required = false) Integer param4)
    { 
        // do something
    }
```

I want to define some constraints on parameters, something like

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value="/v1/{var:.*}/resource", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Response> readDocuments(
        @PathVariable(value = "var") String param1,
        @RequestParam(value = "param2", required = false, defaultValue = "string1") String param2,
        @RequestParam(value = "param3") @Size(min = 1) List<String> param3,
        @RequestParam(value = "param4", required = false) @Min(0) @Max(10) Integer param4)
    { 
        // do something
    }
```

Is it possible? If yes, can I define custom annotations following JSR 303 directives?

Comment: But you already seem to be using the constraints. Probelm is in using existing ones or creating new ones ?

Comment: Yes, you can use from the validation annotations in parameters and can define new annotation.

Comment: don't forget the @Validated annotation